# What does calling 'retain' or 'release' do on a Class?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, should we retain or release a variable of the type `Class`? A `Class` is a pointer to a C struct.

Comment: There may be a bit of a typo in the title in play here - are you referring to a point_er_ to a struct or a struct implementing a point (such as NSPoint?)

Comment: If you're talking about `Class` as defined in the ObjC runtime, then it is an object. If not, could you clarify?

Comment: The Class "object" you get when you say, eg, `[NSArray class]` is not an NSObject and not subject to standard Objective-C garbage collection protocols.  And each one is, in essence, a "singleton" for that specific Objective-C class and so persists forever.

Comment: @HotLicks Every `Class` object is an instance of `NSObject`.  Try `NSLog(@"isKindOfClass: returned %d", (int)[[NSArray class] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that `Class` is declared as a pointer to a `struct` is an implementation detail that you should try to ignore.  You should just treat it as an opaque type that references an Objective-C object representing an Objective-C class.

These `Class` objects in Objective-C are never deallocated.  Once created, they live until the process exits.  Therefore, even though they are true Objective-C objects, you do not need to retain and release them.

As for what specifically happens when you send `retain` or `release` to a `Class` object: nothing.  Each class object has the special value -1 for its retain count.  When the default implementations of `retain` and `release` see a retain count of -1, they do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

A C struct is not an Objective C object, and you can't "retain" or "release" a struct, unless it's a member (e.g. ivar) of an Objective C object which you've retained and released.

And of course you need to allocate space for the struct, whether on the stack or via "`malloc`" (don't forget to "`free`" when you're done with it).

Comment: OP's probably speaking of a `Class` they got from calling `[obj class]` or `[Foo class]`. In both GNU and Apple's implementation, though it is an opaque pointer to `struct Class`, they can act as an Objective-C type, and can be sent messages to. One can indeed do `[[NSObject class] release]`, though, as said in the other answer, nothing happens. You should NOT try to `free()` it.